# Different enumeration for environments

Tags: enumerate

I am writing an article. I created an environment called "theorem". They are enumerated in terms of sections; namely, Theorem 1.2 (second theorem, first section). Now I would like to create two different environments called "remark" and "definition", which must have a normal enumeration independent of each other AND independent of the section. That is, I could write  "Definition 1 and then Remark 1".

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: As a reader this numbering scheme is really annoying, IMO they should follow each other such that a specific one is easier to fine when scrolling though the text. (that is number as `Theorem 1.2`, `Definition 1.3`, `Remark 1.4` etc. To generate these environments look up `\newtheorem` and note that it has several different setup modes. You might want to have a look at the `amsthm` package.